# How can I infer a value in a regular expression when it was specified previously in a series of matches?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have an output from a piece of software that enumerates DNS records (Microsoft dnscmd):

```
Returned records:
@        3600 A 127.0.0.1
         3600 A 127.0.0.4
         3600 A 127.0.0.5

Command completed successfully.
```

I want to match each of the DNS records and extract the named groups only. Those groups are `name`, `ttl`, `type`, and `data`.

To accomplish this, I have created this regular expression:

`(?<name>[^\s]*)(\s*)(?<ttl>\d+)(\s*)(?<type>\w+)(\s*)(?<data>[^\s]*)`

Basically, this gives me what I want. Is it possible to automatically fill the `name` portion for the other records in my matches? The software omits the `name` when it would be repetitive to do so.

I want to avoid writing logic in the software to check if the subsequent matches have a `name` specified or not and just assume that they all do and have the regular expression automatically fill it in when it gives me back the results.

Comment: Define a class with these 4 fields. Take the output of your regex and create instances of the class you just defined as needed. Pass the collection of these instances to whatever uses them. Before you pass them make sure that the name field is set as required.

Comment: @zespri If you could respond with an answer instead of a comment and show some code about what you mean, I think I could understand it better. Right now I can only come to the conclusion that your design would require me to pass in the matches to a class that defines the data structure of a single entry and then communicate the position of the current entry to the class so that it could extract the previously defined name. Remember that the `name` is only defined once until it no longer repeats, so it could differ many times in one match series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is no way to do this with regular expressions, as far as my research has indicated. I have resolved the issue by doing string processing after the match is completed.